# Google App Script timing out while removing Viewers, How to make the script more efficient?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a GAS that I run every month or so to remove Viewers and Editors from GoogleDocs and GoogleSheets that were created over 1 year ago.  I have not found a way to return ONLY the documents which have the specific users I want to remove.

So the code is setup to loop thru all the documents in a specific folder and if the Viewers/Editors do not match the 2 owners, then it removes their access.

The problem is a few folders have a large number of files and it is timing out just reading thru to find out if any Viewers/Editors need to be removed.

Any ideas on how this code could be streamlined or if there is a way to query for only the documents not owned by a specific user?

```
var folder = folders.next();    //assume the match is the first one
folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.getId());   //use the folderID of the year folder
processFolder(folder);    //this starts in with the newest folder modified date under the Proposals/Year folder and works down thru the list until it times out after 5 minutes of running

function processFolder(folder) {
  var asset;
  var users;
  var email;
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var todaysDate = new Date();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var daysCreated = parseInt(((todaysDate - file.getDateCreated()) / 86400000));    //how many days since the document was created 24/3600/1000 = 86,400,000

    if (daysCreated > RETENTION_DAYS) {
      asset = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());

      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          users = asset.getEditors();
        } else {
          users = asset.getViewers();
        }

        for (var cnt = 0; cnt < users.length; cnt++) {
          email = users[cnt].getEmail().toLowerCase();

          if (email != "xxx1@gmail.com" && email != "xxx2@gmail.com") {
            if (i == 0) {   //Editors
              asset.removeEditor(email);
            } else {      //Viewers
              asset.removeViewer(email);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } //processFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

About `how this code could be streamlined or if there is a way to query for only the documents not owned by a specific user?`, for example, if you want to retrieve only the files without including `xxx1@gmail.com` and `xxx2@gmail.com` as the writer and the viewer, how about using `searchFiles` instead of `getFiles`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function processFolder(folder) {
  var emails = ["xxx1@gmail.com", "xxx2@gmail.com"]; // Please set the email addresses.

  var query = emails.map(e => `not '${e}' in writers and not '${e}' in readers`).join(" and ") + " and trashed=false";
  var files = folder.searchFiles(query);
  var todaysDate = new Date();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var daysCreated = parseInt(((todaysDate - file.getDateCreated()) / 86400000));
    if (daysCreated > RETENTION_DAYS) {
      file.getEditors().forEach(e => file.removeEditor(e));
      file.getViewers().forEach(e => file.removeViewer(e));
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the writers and the viewers of the files without including `"xxx1@gmail.com"` and `"xxx2@gmail.com"` as the writer and the viewer are removed.

#### Note:

- When this sample script is run, the writers and the viewers of the files without including `"xxx1@gmail.com"` and `"xxx2@gmail.com"` as the writer and the viewer are removed. So, I would like to recommend testing this script using the sample files. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchfilesparams)

### Added:

From your replying, as another approach, in this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample, the following flow is used.

1. Retrieve all file IDs just under the specific folder using Drive API.
2. Retrieve permission IDs from the files using Drive API.
3. Create the requests for deleting the permissions except for "emails".
4. Delete permissions using Drive API.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install a Google Apps Script library.

In this sample, the batch request is used. In this case, I created a Google Apps Script library for this. So, please install the library. About the method for installing it, you can see it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

This script uses Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### 3. Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and set `emails` and `folderId`. And please run `sample()`. By this, the script is run.

```js
function sample() {
  var emails = ["xxx1@gmail.com", "xxx2@gmail.com"]; // Please set the email addresses.
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.


  // 1. Retrieve all file IDs just under the specific folder using Drive API.
  var list = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var obj = Drive.Files.list({q: `'${folderId}' in parents`, maxResults: 1000, pageToken, fields: "items(id),nextPageToken"});
    if (obj.items.length > 0) list = [...list, ...obj.items.map(({id}) => id)];
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while(pageToken);

  // 2. Retrieve permission IDs from the files using Drive API.
  var req1 = list.map(id => ({method: "GET", endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}/permissions?pageSize=100&fields=permissions(id%2CemailAddress%2Crole)`}))
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var requests1 = {
    batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", // batch path. This will be introduced in the near future.
    requests: req1,
    accessToken: token
  };
  var result1 = BatchRequest.EDo(requests1);

  // 3. Create the requests for deleting the permissions except for "emails".
  var req2 = list.reduce((ar, id, i) => {
    var p = result1[i].permissions;
    if (p.length > 0) {
      p.forEach(e => {
        if (e.role != "owner" && e.emailAddress && !emails.includes(e.emailAddress)) {
          ar.push({method: "DELETE", endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}/permissions/${e.id}`});
        }
      })
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 4. Delete permissions using Drive API.
  var requests2 = {
    batchPath: "batch/drive/v3",
    requests: req2,
    accessToken: token
  };
  var result2 = BatchRequest.EDo(requests2);
}
```

- When this script is run, about all files just under the specific folder, all permissions except for the owner and `emails` are removed.

#### Note:

- This script removes the permissions. Please be careful about this. So in this case, I would like to propose to test using a sample permitted files.

#### Reference:

- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)

Comment: In the above example we can have 2 editors or viewers, such as xxx1@gmail.com or xxx2@gmail.com and we want to keep those people but remove any additional email addresses that may have been added which we do not know to query.  

So doing a "not in 'xxx1@gmail.com'" will not find any matches because xxx1@gmail.com is in fact in the list, so that will exclude the result we are looking for.

We really need to format it as any email address in the list "ignoring" these.  Any thoughts on how to query that?

Comment: @Raptor Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of your reply?

Comment: Is there a wild card that can be used in the email address?  I need to match any email address EXCEPT for the 2 known addresses.

Comment: @Raptor Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply. From your question, I thought that you wanted to retrieve the files except for `"xxx1@gmail.com", "xxx2@gmail.com"` of the writer and viewer. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, what I want to retrieve are the files that have users different than "xxx1@gmail.com", "xxx2@gmail.com".

Comment: @Raptor Thank you for replying. About `what I want to retrieve are the files that have users different than "xxx1@gmail.com", "xxx2@gmail.com".`, my proposed script retrieves such files. So I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize. When I could correctly understand your current issue, I think that I can modify it.

Comment: I have a file that that has the following users:
"xxx1@gmail.com"  -Could be Editor or Viewer, keep this user. 
"xxx2@gmail.com"  -Could be Editor or Viewer, keep this user. 
"DeleteMe@gmail.com" - Could be Editor or Viewer  (I want to only delete this user).

I dont know the name of the user:  "DeleteMe@gmail.com"  so I cant query with "DeleteMe@gmail.com" in writers or "DeleteMe@gmail.com" in readers

The query above wont find this record because:
not '${e}' in writers and not '${e}' in readers
Causes it to be excluded because it has "xxx1@gmail.com" defined as a user.
Make sense?

Comment: what I want to retrieve are the files that have users different than "xxx1@gmail.com", "xxx2@gmail.com"., my proposed script retrieves such files.    -   For this comment, it is not returning a match for me because the files have user:  xxx1@gmail.com  and also a different user, so the match of xxx1@gmail.com as an Editor causes that file to be excluded from the query, when I want to include it.  Hopefully that makes sense, the file has 3 viewers, 2 of which are know as xxx1@gmail.com and xxx2@gmail.com

Comment: @Raptor Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? In that case, I thought that when the batch request is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced. If that was not useful, I apologize again.